# Explorer.exe - Power Usage Spikes w/~1m intervals

Tags: windows, ntfs

Recently my semi-high-end Windows box as been acting up.

I get a big 5 seconds lag every minute or so.

I originally attributed the issue a GPU issue.

Popped open Task Manager to take a peek.

Inside Task Manager, I found that explorer's "Power Usage" spikes simultaneously as the lag.

Looks like "persistence pings"... what would IS suggest?

I generally ghost/snap my boxes, but this box was encrypted and I chickened out of setting up an image/snap due to possible conflicts.

Comment: You really only have 2 options: confirm something suspicious or nuke the machine

Comment: Isn't there seclusion methods?
I know I could simply unplug this SSD from the internet for a week or so, then scan it from a removable drive, but ideally if something could be quicker... is there ANY way to see WHY appX takes the ressources they take, at a given time?

Comment: Sure, there are utilities that can do this, that's part of the investigation, but that's not a security investigation.

Comment: Acknowledged. Thank you for your input.